# Understanding cp in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

```
 cp ${skeleton_dir}/*.cfg ${skeleton_dir}/*.org ./
```

I don't understand what this means, but I have a guess based on the program behavior. It copies the .cfg files to the current directory, but what does the `*.org ./` do?

I want to modify this line to copy *.spop files as well. Will this change do the trick?
(It is hard to verify this easily as the turnaround time on my machine is a day)

```
 cp ${skeleton_dir}/*.cfg ${skeleton_dir}/*.org ./
 cp ${skeleton_dir}/*.spop ${skeleton_dir}/*.org ./
```

Sorry for the stupid questions, but I don't know much about this, and it is difficult to google for "./".

In the future, how would I search for the different variations used with the cp command (this "./"). I know about "man xxx" now, and I read "man cp", but nothing was in there about "./"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the man page for `cp`, you will see that you can specify multiple sources to copy to a target directory.  `./` is the current directory.  So what this does is copy all `.cfg` and `.org` files in `${skeleton_dir}` to the current directory.  Simply add `*.spop`:

```sh
cp ${skeleton_dir}/*.cfg ${skeleton_dir}/*.org ${skeleton_dir}/*.spop ./
```

You could also use brace expansion:

```
cp ${skeleton_dir}/*.{cfg,org,spop} ./
```

Comment: AH!! ./ is current directory. Thank you. Now this is straight forward.  I was confusing it with the run command "./" They are two separate things no?

Oh I see ./ really isn't the run I thought it was all this time. If I type a command into the terminal without this, it says command not found. 

I feel like I have learned something

Comment: @MaxRunFast I don't think that `./` is a valid command .. you may be thinking of `./executable` to run an executable in the current directory

Comment: `.` is the current directory, and `/` is the separator between directories and contents in pathnames. There's essentially no difference between `.` and `./` as the last argument to `cp`.

Comment: He's referring to the `source` command (traditionally spelled `.`), which is only a command name in the first position and without a trailing `/`.